# Passing data from a static table to a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am a Java programmer but my boss doesn't care so he assigned me this project. So I'm seeking out help to the PHP or Javascript developers.

We have data coming in from domain servers that test everything, wiring, heat, etc. All of this is scripted through Regina Rexx to a static table. I want to collect that data without rewriting all the Rexx programming.

Since it's doing it's job, I thought the easy way to do this would be to grab the data from this file which outputs to an html file. I cannot send this link but it comes out just like an ordinary html file with a table.

I want to put this info into a database mysql, PHP, on an Apache server.

***So specificly: Static table to a mysql database.***

Can someone point me in the direction or give me a pointer on this transition. My department are all hardware engineers, and I'm the closest thing to a PHP programmer but I haven't touched a database in 10 years. Yet it's like riding a bike.

Comment: are you trying to edit the HTML file, which contains the data or do you want another php file handle data from this page ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to first fetch data from your static table in php variable

   2. you to create a table in database in which wish to enter data

      3. using php you have to make connection to database

   4.Then you have to fire insert query in your php file to insert

   data in desire table

Comment: God this is a great place. The same offer to you too if you're up in San Jose. William

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to read some file right?

So, you can try that (pure php solution, without any framework):

*This is not the best security way to do that. Try enter in this website to read some good tips about php: http://www.phptherightway.com/*

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("your_data_file.txt", "r");

// try read the file
if ($handle) {

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "myDB";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  // read line by line
  while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
      // insert in mysql and do whatever you want here
      $sql = "INSERT INTO your_table (column_1, column_2)
      VALUES (data1, data2)";

      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
          echo "New record created successfully";
      } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }
  }

  // close the file      
  fclose($handle);

  // close the connection
  $conn->close();  

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good. If I can help you in anyway with any java issues let me know, or I'll buy you a beer if you're up in San Jose....

Comment: I'm glad to help you my friend. Don't forget to vote and mark the answers you want. If you have any problems, let me know. (And yes, about Java I will post some questions any time from now because I'm in a Java + AngularJS project)

Comment: tried to vote you both up but it requires a 15 rep. I'll work on that as soon as I deliver this project. :)